# Handling SMS limit?

Tags: java, android, sms

I'm developing SMS application which sends a lot of SMS's. It is not default SMS app like Google suggests. I'm getting a popup "Messaging is sending a large number of SMS messages. Do you want to allow this app to continue sending messages?". But i want to avoid that and recognize the limit programmatically.

Anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: You are "developing SMS application" and asking us here to tell you why your code pops up with "Messaging is sending a large number of SMS messages..."? I suspect that it is SMS gateway that generates this message, as you failed to disclose **anything** about your application I will fail to tell you what is happening...

Comment: Provide all details if asking technical question

Comment: if i remember correctly there is a limit of 160 characters per message, so all what you need to do is to check is number of characters in message divided by 160 is greater than your maximum number of messages. note that it is not exact formula, as whenever message is split between sereral messages, there are added some additional characters to it

Comment: "Messaging" popup appears when I try to break the limit. Android, JellBean I think, is limited to 30 messages in 30 minutes. SmsManager, class in android which I use to send messges, has five error codes (RESULT_OK, RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE, RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE, RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU, RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF), but one is hidden RESULT_ERROR_LIMIT_EXCEEDED and I can't access it
http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/227096-messaging-sending-large-amount-messages.html 
@user902383 this has nothing to do with characters length:/, but thanks

Comment: @GermannArlington I'm not using SMS gateway. Popup is generated by Android OS

Comment: In this case I suggest you read about Android OS configuration, there may be a way to override this limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMS sending limit was introduced not later than Gingerbread. As far as I know, and I investigated thoroughly, it is generally impossible to override these limits on non-rooted devices. If possible, those are rare exceptions. But, if your app is supposed to send messages from your device only or from controlled number of devices, you may get around this problem by setting SMS_OUTGOING_CHECK_MAX_COUNT to a huge number (say 99999) in:

- /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db

  1. table *secure*
  2. table *system*
- /data/data/com.google.android.gsf/databases/gservices.db

  1. table *main*

Comment: @File: If you happen to have any difficulties sending messages (SMS) from Android devices, feel free to contact me. Handling status reports could be cumbersome. Android's design is far from ideal, in that matter. Anything that takes my minutes, but not hours, is free of charge.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you provide some code on how to set the SMS_OUTGOING_CHECK_MAX_COUNT ? I've written a SMS Sending app and now that it is finished, I've encountered the problem.

Comment: Using adb shell would be the way I'd do it now. Don't know about setting it from code.

Comment: it was fun to receive a reply on a comment after 5 years :) thanks anyway